# GetEntityTypes: configure entity properties using the generic version of .Property<TEntity> in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

In my EF core project I have a few entities that inherit from a base class DBEntity:

```
public abstract class DBEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    public EntityStatus EntityStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I want to set some specific properties with default value for every entity that inherits from DBEntity. Currently I'm using this code:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        var entities = modelBuilder.Model
            .GetEntityTypes()
            .Where(w => w.ClrType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DBEntity)))
            .Select(p => modelBuilder.Entity(p.ClrType));

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {

            entity
                .Property("CreatedOn")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()");

            entity
                .Property("UpdatedOn")
                .HasComputedColumnSql("GETDATE()");

            entity
                .Property("EntityStatus")
                .HasDefaultValue(EntityStatus.Created);

        }
    }
```

This works fine but I don't want to specify property names using string constants (bad for refactoring etc.).

Is there a way to loop through entities that inherit from DBEntity and use property expression to configure default values like this:

```
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    entity
      .Property(k => k.CreatedOn)
      .HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()");

// ....

}
```

**Important constraint:** I cannot directly call modelBuilder.Entity().Property(k => k.CreatedOn) because it will mess up all tables.

Comment: It's possible, but the easier is to use `nameof` instead of string constants.

Comment: @IvanStoev the nameof(DBEntity.CreatedOn) works! What is the other way?

Comment: Create a generic method and call it via reflection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can simply replace the string constants with `nameof(DBEntity.CreatedOn)` etc.

But if you want to work with typed accessors, you can move the base entity configuration code to a **generic** method (with the generic argument being the actual entity type) and call it via reflection.

For instance, add the following to your `DbContext` derived class:

```
static void ConfigureDBEntity<TEntity>(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    where TEntity : DBEntity
{
    var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>();

    entity
        .Property(e => e.CreatedOn)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()");

    entity
        .Property(e => e.UpdatedOn)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("GETDATE()");

    entity
        .Property(e => e.EntityStatus)
        .HasDefaultValue(EntityStatus.Created);

}
```

and then use something like this:

```
var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model
        .GetEntityTypes()
        .Where(t => t.ClrType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DBEntity)));

var configureMethod = GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods.Single(m => m.Name == nameof(ConfigureDBEntity));
var args = new object[] { modelBuilder };
foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
    configureMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType).Invoke(null, args);
```

Comment: I am trying to implement your suggested solution but my base entity takes a generic type argument (BaseEntity<T>). So when I pass the typeof(BaseEntity) to IsSubclassOf(), it gives an error: `Error CS0305 Using the generic type 'BaseEntity<T>' requires 1 type arguments`. I am not sure how to pass the type of a class with type arguments in this case. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @SuhaibSyed Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275567/how-to-apply-common-configuration-to-all-entities-in-ef-core/53326519#53326519 is an example how you can do that - `IsBaseEntity` method, you can eliminate `out T` parameter if you don`t need it.

Answer (score 3):

What about, in your context, adding something like this

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void AddTimestamps()
    {
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => (x.Entity is DBEntity) && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));

        var now = DateTime.UtcNow; // current datetime

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((DBEntity)entity.Entity).CreatedOn = now;
                ((DBEntity)entity.Entity).EntityStatus = EntityStatus.Created;
            }
            ((DBEntity)entity.Entity).UpdatedOn= now;
        }
    }
```

You have the drawback to not enforcing those default values at db level (at this point you are db agnostic) but stil able to refactor