# How would you create your ef core 2.0 model with object property generation having inheritance in OnModelCreating?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

So lets you pretend in your Model class (whichever you want to call it that inherits from DbContext) and you override `OnModelCreating`. You have a base class called `DBDateTime` and let's say it looks something like this ->

```
public class DbDateTime
{
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

and then you have a class that inherits from it --->

```
   public class MyTable : DbDateTime
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string prop1{ get; set; }
}
```

in your model and your `OnModelCreating` you would have something like ->

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {


        modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>(entity => 
        {
           entity.Property(x => x.CreatedDateTime).Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
        })
     }
```

This is fine for one table that inherits from a set of properties but if you have 10 tables that inherit from such a class is there a way to use some sort of inheritance with property generation in ef core 2.0? I would love to write code once and set property generation rules for the base class so I don't have to write it over and over again per class that inherits from that base class.

Comment: Any ideas by anyone? :(

Comment: What `entity.Property(x => x.CreatedDateTime).Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;` this line does?

Comment: why do you need `PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore`?

Comment: @viveknuna this will say after you do OnSaveChanges to not actually commit that property to the database from ef so the value it self will never be updated through ef in my knowledge or at least will try to

Comment: Then why do you need this property ?

Comment: I would need to return it to the clients

Comment: I think you can ignore this line , because this property won’t change unless u change it explictly.

Comment: You can adjust the solution from [GetEntityTypes: configure entity properties using the generic version of .Property<TEntity> in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676508/getentitytypes-configure-entity-properties-using-the-generic-version-of-proper) for your needs.

Comment: @IvanStoev So is my question kind of a duplicate? Is there a way to credit you for the answer

Comment: You are welcome mate. If it helped solving your issue, that's enough for me :)